# LLVM variadic parameters

Tags: llvm, variadic-functions

When I compile a c file to LLVM-IR which uses the printf function, I get a function declaration line, which looks as follows:

```
declare i32 @printf(i8* nocapture readonly, ...) local_unnamed_addr #2
```

I now wonder how LLVM translates the variadic parameter? Doesn't the `printf(char *, ...)` refer to a macro in the standard library?
Also how can I make such a declaration in the LLVM library?

Comment: You should see the _va_arg structure being setup by the caller and consumed by the receiver. Pretty much follows the same model as you see in C.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After some further research, I found the correspondent section in the LLVM language reference: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#int-varargs
LLVM really just has its own intrinsics which work the same as the C macros in stdarg.h

Comment: Yes, there are a good number of intrinsics. As I assume you are either generating IR directly or using the llvm libraries you would find it supported